# I set my telegram bot webhook, but do not send the telegram. Why?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I set webhook my telegram bot with setwebhook method but when I send a message in bot don't take this in my URL.

```
    https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setwebhook?url=https://www.example.com/bot/temp.php
```

In my host I use PHP language for take and analysis and answer that. and I user this command for get updates from bot.

```
    $update = file_get_contents(“php://input”);
```

But after run this line $update is empty.
I haven't problem with take updates without setwebhook bot when I use webhook don't take data.

result run getWebhookinfo is:

```
    {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://example.com/bot/temp.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}
```

Do I have to be true "has_custom_cere"?
Thanks for help me

Answer (score 3):

Mohammad, I think a PHP error occurred when telegram sends the request to you. Following code should works fine for getting the Telegram request.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json);
```

I think your script stop before this code. I suggest you to enable PHP debug mode and check the error log.

Comment: I check my error log. but I haven't any error about this php file. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can find out problem via following method:

Check [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) method, make sure your webhook URL is correct, and no `last_error_message` field.

POST similar data to your server, [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) is some data you can use in `curl -d JSON`, just copy it and run on your own server.

At last, check your CDN config (if you had applied on that server), temporary disable flooding or any check.

Comment: result of getWebhookinfo is:

         {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://example.com/bot/temp.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}

Comment: I use sharing hosting. how I can check my CDN config?

Comment: in result "has_custom_certificate" is false. Do I have to be true

Comment: I write answer in my main question, top of page

Answer (score 0):

What is the outcome of the `/getwebhookinfo` method and could you post it here?
Please check if you SSL certificate valid (happend once to me) and what shows if you call the website in your browser (any php errors?).

I would have commented that, but I don´t have enough rep... Sorry :/

Comment: SSL/TLS1.2 is accepted telegram there are in my hosting.

Comment: Okay and the `/getwebhookinfo`says?

Comment: {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://example.com/bot/temp.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}

Comment: I check error log but I haven't any error about this php file. :(

Comment: What I would do in your case: Reduce the php to just send an echo (one line php), check if the api query works without the bot `/sendmessage` and check if I got everywhere the right bot token...     And to answer your question: no the **custom cert doesn´t have to be true**.

Comment: you still have the problem? Did the suggestion help? @mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this way and if you don't get answer, your `PHP` has problem :
1- Revoke your `Auth Key` from `BotFather` by typing ***/revoke***
2- Reset your `Webbhook` by new `Auth Key` :

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook?url=https://www.website.com/bot_path
```

Notice #1 : `setWebhook` is case sensitive and `W` keyword must be capital. 
Notice #2 : If you're using `CMS` such as Codeigniter, Laravel, Zend etc. It doesn't need to put `.php` after your `bot_path` and if not use it.
Notice #3 : If you want to delete last `Webhook` that you have set, You just need to write above `url` without `?url=` at the rest.
3- After all you receive this message from telegram :

> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

Now you can test your Bot, But be aware that do this way to check your `Auth Key` and If there is no problem, absolutely your `PHP` code has problem. If you have problem yet please contact me on website to solve it [Graphap](https://graphap.com) and then put the right answer here.
I've told to recheck this way because I had problem frequently because of `Auth Key` which not working But now it works as well.